# Update Query Using Most Recent Value from Second Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am a relative newbie on Access with a question far above my skills

I am storing information about Employees in an Access table called Current Employees that contains First Name, Last Name, Employee ID, etc.

Since employees are changing shifts/positions frequently I needed a way to store their history of Job Title, Shift, etc. without storing two records for an employee with a lot of redundant data.

So I created a second table called Assignment History with a relationship between the Employee ID, where there can be multiple entries for the same Employee ID, that looks like

```
Employee ID | Assigned As Of | Job Title | Shift
1234        | 01/01/2017     | Manager   | A
1234        | 12/01/2016     | Salesman  | A 
5678        | 12/01/2016     | Salesman  | B
```

Now for various form reasons, I want to put the most recent value back into my first table Current Employees under a Current Title position like so

```
Employee ID | FName         | Last Name | Current Job
1234        | John          | Smith     | Manager
5678        | Steve         | Adams     | Salesman
```

The closest I've been able to get is a Create Table Query into a third table CurrAssign where the code is

```
SELECT a.* 
INTO CurrAssign
FROM AssignmentHistory AS a 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT max(a.AssignedAsOf) AS LatestDate, a.EmployeeID 
     FROM AssignmentHistory AS a GROUP BY a.EmployeeID)  
AS SubMax 
ON (a.EmployeeID = SubMax.EmployeeID) 
AND (a.AssignedAsOf = SubMax.LatestDate);
```

Any help on how to change this query to an update on Current Employee? Or is there a better way to format and store this information?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple "look up" approach. Would this work?

```
SELECT ce.EmployeeID, ce.FName, ce.LName,
(SELECT TOP 1 ah.[Job Title] FROM AssignmentHistory ah WHERE ah.EmployeeID = ce.EmployeeID ORDER BY ah.AssignedAsOf DESC) AS CurrentJob--Look up Current Job
FROM CurrentEmployee ce
```

Answer (score 0):

Because MS Access requires update queries to be [updateable](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html), consider using nested domain aggregates, `DLookUp` and `DMax` in query:

```sql
UPDATE Employees e    
SET e.[Current Job] = DLookUp("[Job Title]", "[Assignment History]", 
                              "[Employee ID]=" & e.[Employee ID] & 
                              " AND [Assigned As Of]=#" & 
                              DMax("[Assigned As Of]", "[Assignment History]", 
                                   "[Employee ID]=" & e.[Employee ID]) & "#")
```